# What is the default text size in R base graphics?

Tags: r, graphics, fonts, size

I have to write a document and the instructions are really stricts. The text size has to be 7pt inside all figures (axis labels, ticks labels, legends). For some reasons I use the base graphics package and cannot use extra packages like ggplot2. In the options of "graphics" (`?par`), I only see this `cex` parameter and derivatives that permit to fix the text size **relative** to a default size.

What is the default font size of R graphics ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For all of R's graphical devices, the default text size is 12 points but it can be reset by including a `pointsize` argument to the function that opens the graphical device. From `?pdf`:

> pointsize: the default point size to be used.  Strictly speaking, in
>             bp, that is 1/72 of an inch, but approximately in points.
>             Defaults to '12'.

For example, open a device like this:

```
## pdf
pdf("plot.pdf", pointsize=7)

## bitmap
bmp("plot.bmp", pointsize=7)

## graphics window on screen
x11(pointsize=7)

## etc., etc.  (See ?Devices for a list of available graphics devices.)
```

and then, after plotting to it, close it with `dev.off()`.

Comment: In practice, I've only ever relied on this being precisely accurate for `pdf` and `ps` devices, so I can't vouch for the good behavior of the others.

Comment: Also important is to create the plot at the required size.  I have had people create a graph on the screen using the defaults, then save that to a file, shrink it to 1/4 the original size to insert into an article, then complain that the text is too small.  When calling the graphics function such as `pdf` or `png` or others you can specify the dimensions of the plot, choose ones that match the size that you want the final product to be and don't resize.

Comment: Thanks for answers, I was not searching in the good direction !

Comment: On the window size issue, be sure to specify the x/y pinch arguments to get it right (e.g. `windows(width=6, height=4.5, xpinch=100, ypinch=100)`).  This specifies the pixels per inch horizontally and vertically.  Otherwise, the output can be unpredictable when you finally save it to file.